# running a background process in pythonanythere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I just want to know that if the following is possible:

I want to run a local socket program in background in the pythonanywhere and want to access the socket from django app registered in same pythonanywhere domain.

Actually I want to run a machine learning algorithm as a socket program which i want to access by the web client. I want to run a single process for any number of client because I dont think its wise to train the algorithm every time a new client gets connected. Can I do that.

for being more clear:

I want the trained machine learning program to be launched only once in the server and the web portal should receive the inputs parameters from clients and send back the prediction after interacting with the program . All the client has to be served by this single instance of machine learning program so that the main program has to be trained only once.

Please suggest any other way to perform this if any..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Written as is, I don t even understand what you re asking... What cause you a problem? Why do you need pythonanywhere?

Comment: I want to run a machine learning algorithm and this should be up for entire time and accessible via web.. suggest me here please

Comment: You can't run arbitrary socket servers on PythonAnywhere, but I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. If your machine learning algorithm keeps its training data only in memory, then a machine restart will clear all your data. But if your algorithm saves stuff to disk then your web app can just read that for a request and you don't need a socket server.

Comment: yea! I can do that!, It never crossed my mind and what I was thinking...thanks man